# Friends birthday is not showing in facebook 2.7 graph API

Tags: android, facebook

I am using mentioned below code to get birthday of my friend in Graph Explorer. But Birthday is not showing.

/v2.7/me?fields=friends{birthday}

Answer (score 1):

You can not access people’s birthdays just because they are friends with your app user.

Every user has to personally grant your app `user_birthday` permission to access their birthday; otherwise you have no access to that field.

Comment: is any way to contact to Facebook? I have a birthday reminder app thats why i need to implement facebook friends birthday.

Comment: Your app won’t get special treatment. This is about protecting people’s privacy, and they won’t make an exception for you.